# How does PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged work?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm intersted in the details of this method.
How and by what are property's value changes being tracked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew Smith has a [cool blog post](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/) about it which I think it can be helpful for you.

> The solution that I have seen given for this is to get to the
>   `PropertyDescriptor` and use its `AddValueChanged` method to provide an
>   `EventHandler` to receive a notification when the property has changed.
>   Sometimes, the reply will mention/use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`
>   directly but its the same thing since that is just a derived
>   PropertyDescriptor that provides additional information about the
>   underlying DependencyProperty it represents. You  can get to this
>   property descriptor in a few ways but the most common are to get it
>   from the TypeDescriptor.GetProperties method or using the
>   DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty.
>
> The issue with this approach is that it will root your object so **it
>   will never get collected by the GC**. There have been plenty of
>   discussions about how hooking events (particularly static events) can
>   root your object so I won’t go into great detail there. While it does
>   not seem that you are hooking a static event in this case, in essence
>   you are. When you add a handler to a property descriptor, that
>   property descriptor stores the delegate in a hashtable keyed by the
>   object whose property you are hooking. A delegate/handler is basically
>   a pointer to a method on an object (or no object if its for a static
>   method) so that means the property descriptor has a reference to your
>   object as well as the object whose value you are watching (since that
>   is the key into the hashtable). The property descriptors themselves
>   are cached statically so the hashtable is kept around and therefore
>   your object and the one you are watching are as well.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately his post does not give answeres to all questions. As far as I inderstand reflection system intercepts the call of the setter not the real change of the value, does it?

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyDescriptor` is an abstract class, so there are presumably many answers to how the value changed event is fired depending on the specific implementation you have at hand. But probably a common case is when a `PropertyDescriptor` has been acquired **through reflection**, in which case I think an object of `ReflectPropertyDescriptor` is returned.

Looking in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/componentmodel/ReflectPropertyDescriptor.cs,cf693c889afd5cca) for that class, you can see that the event is raised ONLY when the `SetValue()` method is called. To my understanding this means that if you simply did this:

`someObject.A = "value";`

there would be no `ValueChanged` event raised.

However if you got the `ReflectPropertyDescriptor` for property `A` and used it to indirectly set the value, like this:

`descriptor.SetValue(someObject, "value");`

that would raise the event.

To think about this from another point of view, it seems the CLR has no way to actually raise an event at a more fundamental level when a property value is set. I assume something like that would have overhead that would ordinarily be undesirable because each set (really just a function call) would have to check for event subscribers even if there were none, each time a value is set on any property.